# Fortran Array Entries Corrupted?

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran

I'm writing a subroutine that transform a regular vector into the one with only non-zero elements. Say, vector `a=(0,0,1,2,3)'` (n by 1). Then the non-zero vector is `c=(1,2,3)`, and the row index is recorded as `ic=(0,0,0,1,2,3)` where `ic(1)=0`, `ic(i+1)-ic(i)` is the number of non-zero elements in `i-th` row. The vector index `jc=(1,1,1)` with size 3 as there are 3 non-zero entries. See the sparse matrix wiki for FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix.

Despite its simplicity, I'm having troubles in running the following code named `sparsem.f90`

```
!This subroutine coverts a regular sparse matrix a into a CSR form
MODULE SPARSEM
CONTAINS 

SUBROUTINE vsparse(a,c,jc,ic,counta,ierr,myid)
IMPLICIT NONE

REAL(8), INTENT(IN):: a(:)
INTEGER, INTENT(IN):: counta,myid
REAL(8), INTENT(OUT):: c(counta)
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT):: jc(counta),ic(size(a)+1)
INTEGER:: ierr,countaa,i
character(len=90):: filename

ierr=0

jc=0
c=0.0d0
ic=0

PRINT *, 'SIZE OF A IN VSPARSE', size(a),count(a>0.0d0),counta

IF (COUNT(a>0.0d0) /= counta) THEN
  ierr=1
  PRINT *, 'ERROR: number count of non-zero a(i,j) is not', counta
ELSE
  countaa=0
  ic(1)=0

  DO i=1,size(a)
    IF (a(i) > 0.0d0 ) THEN
      countaa=countaa+1
      c(countaa)=a(i)
      ic(i+1)=ic(i)+1
      jc(countaa)=1
      IF (countaa<100)    PRINT *,'checkcheckcheck', a(i), &
  countaa,jc(countaa),c(countaa)，jc(1:5)

    ELSE
      ic(i+1)=ic(i)
    END IF
  END DO

  PRINT *, 'JCJCJCJC',jc(1:5)


END IF

 IF (myid==7) THEN
    WRITE(filename,'("sparsedens_dcheck",I1,".txt")') myid+1
   OPEN(UNIT=212101, FILE="/home/wenya/Workspace/Model4/valuef/"//filename,ACTION='write',status='replace')
   DO i=1,counta+1
     IF (i<=counta) THEN
       WRITE(212101,*) c(i),jc(i)
     ELSE
       WRITE(212101,*) 0.0D0,0
     END IF
   END DO
   CLOSE(212101)
 END IF



return
END SUBROUTINE vsparse
END MODULE SPARSEM
```

So the three print `jc` codes shall give `1 1 1 1 1...`. Yet starting from the second print `jc` code, the result is 6750960 6750691 6750692 .... The array of `jc` has size 9,000,000. And I know the first 2250000 element is 0.

To replicate this problem, here is the main program

```
PROGRAM MAIN
USE SPARSEM
IMPICIT NONE

REAL(8):: dens_last(9000000)
REAL(8), ALLOCATABLE :: dens(:)
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: ic(:),jc(:)
INTEGER:: i


dens_last(1:2250000)=0.0d0
dens_last(2250001:9000000)=1.0d0/6750000.0d0

ncount=count(dens_last>0.0d0)
ALLOCATE(dens(ncount), ic(9000000+1), jc(ncount)_
CALL VSPASEM(dens_last, dens, jc, ic, ncount,ierr)

DEALLOCATE(dens,ic,jc)



END PROGRAM MAIN
```

I am using `gfortran 6.3.0` and `openmpi` latest version on a `UBUNTU 17.04` computer. Although `openmpi` is not used in this example, it's used in the rest of the program. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Which debugging options did you use? Try `-g -fbacktrace -Warn -fcheck=all`. Please try to provide a [mcve] consisting of the subroutine and a simple code that calls it so that others can test the code. Note that `real(8)` is ugly and not portable (but does not cause this problem).

Comment: I meant `-Wall`, not `-Warn`, the important one is `-fcheck=all` anyway.

Comment: @VladimirF thanks! Since the rest of the program is compiled using `mpif90`, thus the run command in the `Makefile` is `mpirun -np 8  ./output.out`. How can I pass the options you mentioned to `gfortran`? I tried `FCFLAGS= -g` following this link https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building, yet failed.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You're right. I can skip the `jc` to avoid the problem. Yet it confuses me why the code behaves this way.

Comment: Just ditch the Makefile, take the [mcve] that you made and compile it manually. And copy the results here as well.

Comment: Now the program calls a subroutine called `vspasem` (with 6 arguments) while the module provides a subroutine called `vsparse` which takes 7 arguments.  I haven't a clue what you expect us to help you debug !

Comment: After another look, the program posted is no compilable.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark @Vladimir F I found that I allocate a dimension less than the `size(dens)+1`  to `ic` in my original code.. So I would delete the question once you two see this post..Many thanks for your time!